# Tangent space to $O(n)$ with curves

Tags: differential-geometry

The map $f: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow S(n), A \mapsto A^tA$ is a submersion, where $S(n)$ are symmetric matrices. Therefore, $T_Q O(n) = \ker d_Qf$. I would like to understand what's wrong in this reasoning using only tangent curves.

We take a generic curve in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ centered at $Q$, and take the equivalence class, i.e. we consider a tangent vector in $T_Q(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$. Because the usual identifications, this tangent vector can be taken to be $v = [\xi \mapsto Q+\xi M]$ for some matrix $M$. Applying $d_Q f$ we get $d_Q f v = [\xi \mapsto I + \xi ^2 M^tM+\xi (M^tQ+Q^tM)]$.

To understand $T_Q O(n)$ we check what happens if $[\xi \mapsto I + \xi ^2 M^tM+\xi (M^tQ+Q^tM)]$ is equivalent to the constant curve at $I$. This happens if and only if $M^tQ+Q^tM = 0$, therefore we can conclude that  $$T_Q O(n) = \{ [\xi \mapsto Q+\xi M], \text{ with $M$ a matrix, and } M^tQ+Q^tM=0\}$$

However, $\xi \mapsto Q+\xi M$ is not in general a curve in $O(n)$, so, what's wrong here?

Comment: $Q+\xi M$ describe the tangent line of the manifold $O(n)$ at the point $Q$. There is no reason taht this line is in $O(n)$

Answer (score 1):

What you obtain is actually
$$\mathbb di(T_Q O(n)) = \{ [\xi \mapsto Q+\xi M], \text{ with $M$ a matrix, and } M^tQ+Q^tM=0\}$$
where $i:O(n)\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is the canonical inclusion. Then, you can derive that :
$$T_Q(O(n)) = \Big\{[\gamma], \text{ with } \gamma:\mathbb R\overset{\mathcal C^\infty}{\rightarrow} O(n),\gamma(0)= Q \\\hspace{6cm}\text{ and } \gamma \sim \xi\mapsto Q+\xi M \text{ with }MQ^T+QM^T=0\Big\}$$

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first statement? I was actually using a theorem in a differential geometry book, clearly too pedantically. Nice username, by the way.